# SQL query display onto window

Tags: java, sql, eclipse

I'm trying to output the sql query results onto a window of sorts when the button is clicked but when clicked it displays `"org.hsqlb.jdbc.JDBCResultSet@75fbe2c7"`, dont know if it's relative the number at the end changes  my database connection works

```
JButton btnReview = new JButton("Review Seller Requests");
btnReview.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        try {
            String query = "SELECT email FROM seller_requests";
            PreparedStatement pSt = connect.prepareStatement(query);
            rS = pSt.executeQuery();

            if(rS.next()) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, rS);
            }

            pSt.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Can JOptionPane be used or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To view the results, you need to get the appropriate column value from the `ResultSet` object after calling its `next` method. You can use [`ResultSet#getString(int columnIndex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString(int)) to do this:

```
if(rS.next()) {
    String email = rS.getString(1);  // column index starts at 1, not zero.
    // display email
}
```

Comment: I used this and works with no problems so thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Or you can also get the column value by using the column names of the table.

```
rS.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
```

so in your case it should be.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, rS.getString("COLUMN_NAME")); // for example
```